# Xamarin: error en empaquetado de APK

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error (bastante genérico) a la hora de intentar publicar mi APK en *Xamarin Android*:

> "No se puede crear el archivo de almacenamiento debido a un error en el proceso de empaquetado."

El problema se produce al intentar archivar utilizando el perfil *Release*. Con el perfil *Debug* funciona correctamente.

Otro dato importante es que al principio el perfil *Release* me daba error al compilar, algo de que no se podían escribir mas líneas en un archivo porque la ruta era demasiado larga. Para solucionarlo, habilite los paths largos para Win32 (configuración de políticas de grupo de Windows 10). Ahora compila ok, pero no archiva.

Buscando diferencias con otros proyectos *Xamarin* con los que puedo archivar, no encuentro nada llamativo.

Alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema o si hay algún log donde buscar mas información sobre el error?

Comment: Primero que nada no se empaqueta nada en Debug, no te lo permite. Las rutas larga siempre tienen problemas con los proyectos. Deberias Cambiar tu proyecto a una ruta mas corta, despues limpiar y compilar en Release, despues te pedira que tengas una firma creada, para firmar el apk y esta misma firma tiene que ser la que uses en el playstore y luego puedes crear el apk

Comment: Es algo tarde para responder. Pero, en mi caso cuando me pasa eso.
1. Abro y cierro la aplicación.
2. Coloco en modo debug y compilo.
3. Una vez la compilación fue exitosa. Cambias a release y vuelves a compilar.
4. Una vez no tengas tareas de segundo plano (las vez en la esquina inferior derecha).Realizas el archivado y te funcionará. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede porque la ruta de la carpeta es muy larga, tienes que cambiar la ruta en el Visual studio, en herramientas -> opciones -> Xamarin, y cambias la ubicación de los archivos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o puedes cambiar el nombre de las carpetas por unos mas cortos, dejo el link donde encontré la respuesta https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5584